# How to use goto in nested loop in .bat script window

Tags: windows, batch-file, goto

I'm a newbie, I don't really understand how to use goto. I have a small piece of code below. Why does the outer loop only run once?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /L %%i in (1,1,3) do (
    echo parent loop no: %%i
    set "jump=0"
    for /L %%j in (1,1,5) do (
        echo child loop no: %%j
        if %%j equ 2 (
            set "jump=1"
            goto :jump_label
        )
    )
    :jump_label
    echo test
)
pause
```

The result I received is as below:

```
parent loop no: 1
child loop no: 1
child loop no: 2
test
```

Expect result:

```
parent loop no: 1
child loop no: 1
child loop no: 2
parent loop no: 2
child loop no: 1
child loop no: 2
parent loop no: 3
child loop no: 1
child loop no: 2
test
```

Please help!

Comment: You cannot have labels within a `for` loop. You could create the label outside of the `for` loop, then `call` it instead. _Obviously you would need to prevent the labelled code from being run when not `call`ed too_.

Comment: in additition to compo's statements, the logic your attempting may well be possible using `If` based conditional testing to control the flow of execution. If you can't figure out how to implement the control flow via goto, Make a new question outlining the specific control flow you are attempting to implement.

Comment: @Compo In some programming languages, if a condition in an if statement is passed, I can use the break statement to skip remaining iterations of inner loops while allowing the outer loops to continue. However, with the goto statement, the outer loop is executed only once. I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: @T3RR0R 
I have edited the post, could you please check again? I'm seeking to understand how the goto statement works when used within nested loops.

Comment: It happens @SơnNguyễnThái, because, in this programming language, **You cannot have labels within a `for` loop.**

Comment: @SơnNguyễnThái As already stated, that is a different question, unrelated to Goto. The appropriate thing to do is ask a new question

Comment: In batch, any `goto` breaks any loops/code blocks. It breaks **all** of them when nested. You simply are back at "top level" after a `goto` (destroying any meta-variables `%%i etc, as they are only valid within the loop). ("higher" languages don't even have a `goto`, probably exactly of that reason)